# AWS Cognito refreshing tokens against a different user pool also returns valid tokens

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-cognito

I was trying the AWS CLI for cognito.

I have a refresh token issued by user pool, let's say "**A**"  with client ID "**clientA**".

I used this against a different user pool "**B**" in the same region. I specified client ID as "clientA" instead of B's own. This command worked and returned new access and ID tokens successfully.

```
$  aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth --user-pool-id "B" 
--region eu-west-1 --client-id clientA --auth-flow 
REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH --auth-parameters "REFRESH_TOKEN=<refresh-token-from-A>"
```

It seems like AWS Cognito does not really use the "user-pool-id" parameter and only considers the client ID. Or otherwise this is a security loophole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation isn't massively clear about this, but the `REFRESH_TOKEN` flow does not use the `client-id` or `user-pool-id` as these are effectively provided *by* the Refresh Token itself. (Although the body won't validate without them...)

If you do some further commands on the CLI you'll see that the tokens you got back from that command only allow you to act as the originally issued client-id/user-pool-id.